# Who owns the ARP Table and FDB in the context of a linux network namespace?

Tags: linux, networking

I'm trying to understand linux overlay networks. I understand a bridge serves the combined function of an L2 Switch and L3 Router. It uses an ARP table for *IP -> MAC mapping*, and an FDB for *MAC -> iface mapping*. But where exactly do these tables recide and who 'owns/manages' them?

For instance, suppose you create a linux **bridge** in a **network namespace** and attach 2 **veth interfaces** to it.

1. Does each veth interface maintain its own ARP & FDB table?
2. Or does the bridge maintain one table for all interfaces?
3. Or is it the namespace that manages the table?

Answer (score 0):

No, a (linux kernel) bridge doesn't combine the functions of an L2 switch and an L3 router.

A bridge works purely on level 2, like a switch, which the optimization that if it is known that a certain MAC address will be behind a certain port, than packets with an L2 destination of that MAC address will only leave through that port, instead of getting sent to all ports. That's what the FDB is for. However, many hardware switches use the same optimization.

A linux bridge is different from a hardware switch in two aspects: The way to assign ports to this bridge is to use other network interfaces (which usually will be physical ethernet interfaces). In that case, they loose their L3 functionality, and any IP address assigned to them gets ignored etc. Also, there's a special network interface (the one of the bridge itself, `br0` etc.) that acts like if it was a port of a hardware switch directly connected to the computer via a physical interface.

The ARP table has nothing to do with all that.

A namespace isolates everything network related, so every namespace will have its own ARP table, its own list of network interfaces, and among those potentially bridges etc.

(There is a way to have a bridge send up chosen packets to L3 and `iptables` to form what some people call a "brouter", a combination of bridge and router, but this has to be enabled, and a bridge by itself can work just fine without that functionality).